# Value Error: Label must be of length 'x' python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib

I know there is some similar question asked, but i have test all the solution and it still give me the same error which is **Value error: Label must be of length 'x'**. Below is snippets of the code and data set in case needed.

```
data=[['E001', 'M', 34, 123,'Normal',350],
      ['E002', 'F', 40, 114, 'Overweight', 450],
      ['E003', 'F', 37, 135, 'Obesity', 169],
      ['E004', 'M', 30, 139, 'Underweight',189],
      ['E005', 'F', 44, 117, 'Underweight',183],
      ['E006', 'M', 36, 121, 'Normal', 80],
      ['E007', 'M', 33, 133, 'Obesity', 166],
      ['E008', 'F', 26, 140, 'Normal', 120],
      ['E009', 'M', 32, 133, 'Normal', 75],
      ['E0010','M', 36, 133, 'Underweight', 40]]

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['EMPID','Gender','Age','Sales','BMI','Income'])

label=list(df.columns.values)
print(label)
plt.pie(df['Age'],labels=label,autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What line does this error occur?

Comment: it is on the plt.pie(df['Age'],labels=label,autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True) line which get the error @Bartek

Comment: Ah, this is because you are specifying `labels` as `label`, where-in it should be `labels=df['Age']. There is a mismatch in length on the x and labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your df["age"] need to be the same length as your labels list.
Run this code below and see how it works.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=[['E001', 'M', 34, 123,'Normal',350],
          ['E002', 'F', 40, 114, 'Overweight', 450],
          ['E003', 'F', 37, 135, 'Obesity', 169],
          ['E004', 'M', 30, 139, 'Underweight',189],
          ['E005', 'F', 44, 117, 'Underweight',183],
          ['E006', 'M', 36, 121, 'Normal', 80],
          ['E007', 'M', 33, 133, 'Obesity', 166],
          ['E008', 'F', 26, 140, 'Normal', 120],
          ['E009', 'M', 32, 133, 'Normal', 75],
          ['E0010','M', 36, 133, 'Underweight', 40]]

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['EMPID','Gender','Age','Sales','BMI','Income'])
df.head()
label=list(df.columns.values)
print(label)
new_list = list(df['Age'])
plt.pie(new_list[4:],labels=label,autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

In labels you need to pass the `df['Age']` so it can show the percentage of each age

```
data=[['E001', 'M', 34, 123,'Normal',350],
      ['E002', 'F', 40, 114, 'Overweight', 450],
      ['E003', 'F', 37, 135, 'Obesity', 169],
      ['E004', 'M', 30, 139, 'Underweight',189],
      ['E005', 'F', 44, 117, 'Underweight',183],
      ['E006', 'M', 36, 121, 'Normal', 80],
      ['E007', 'M', 33, 133, 'Obesity', 166],
      ['E008', 'F', 26, 140, 'Normal', 120],
      ['E009', 'M', 32, 133, 'Normal', 75],
      ['E0010','M', 36, 133, 'Underweight', 40]]

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['EMPID','Gender','Age','Sales','BMI','Income'])

label=list(df.columns.values)
print(label)
plt.pie(df['Age'],labels=df['Age'],autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

## OUTPUT

[image]